# Why is this variable not being reassigned in case

Tags: bash

This is essentially part a calculator in UNIX script. In this part of the script, using MR, MS, or M+ will yield different results. Here is the code in question:

```
while true
do
    echo 'please enter operand'
    read operand2
    if [ "$operand2" = "X" ]
    then
        exit
    fi
    case "$operand2" in
    "MS")
            (mem=$sum)
            echo "$sum -> M"
            continue;;
    'MR')
            (operand2=$mem)
            echo $operand2
            echo "M -> $mem"
            break;;
    'M+')
            temp=$(( sum+mem ))
            echo "$sum + $mem = $temp"
            mem=$(( sum+mem ))
            continue;;
    *[0-9]*)
            break;;
    *)
            echo "Sorry, $operand2 is not a valid input"
            continue;;
    esac
done
```

The problem with the code is that with the input of "MR", the variable `operand2` remains assigned to the string "MR" rather than being reassigned to the value stored in the `mem` variable.

I have tried adding an `echo` statement for `operand2`, as I thought this may be a scope issue, however, the echo returns "MR" anyways. I have also tried moving around the reassignment within the case, which doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Why did you put parentheses around the assignment?

Comment: Do you know what they do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to use double or single brackets, parentheses, curly braces](/q/2188199/4518341) (though it's much more general)

Comment: In the future, please make a [mre], which can help you understand the problem better. Here, `case` is irrelevant. You could reproduce the problem in two lines: `(foo=bar); echo $foo` (which prints a blank line) or `(foo=bar); declare -p foo` (which results in an error).

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses around the assignments makes the assignments happen in subshells and the value you set in those subshells will not be visible to the outer shell.
Make it

```bash
mem=$sum
```

and

```bash
operand2=$mem
```